# How to prevent flickering with duplicate webfont definition?

Tags: css, webfonts

Suppose I have a webfont defined in some `@font-face` CSS rule. At runtime I want to add more CSS via JS. I'm not talking about the [FOUT at load time](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/).

It just so happens that my framework occasionally adds **the very same `@font-face` rule** again. Turns out this makes Firefox and Chrome try to re-download (or load the disk-cached) font file, and this causes flickering.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hg9Pc/ <sub>(Firefox; this particular case works fine in Chrome)</sub>

Is there a way to prevent this flickering other than "just don't do it"?
Crazy cache headers or something?

Comment: You should look into why your framework adds the rule twice.

Comment: @RoToRa As a matter of fact, I partially wrote the framework myself and it's pretty hard to prevent this issue. It's certainly possible, but would require loads of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can prevent the flicker if you in fact invoke another `@font-face` call. However, it seems like you might be able to do one of the following two things:

1. Have the javascript sift through and delete out that extra definition before loading it into the page (this would admittedly be a rather difficult task I think, but not impossible).
2. If you can, define the original implementation by a different font name. For example, the original font may be defined as `My Arial` so later when `Arial` (I know you would not use `@font-face` for Arial, it is just for an example) loads via the framework (both of which point to the same file for definition), the flicker should not occur because the page is not actually trying to replace the `My Arial` definition. The problem with this would be if there is ever an instance where you ***do*** want it to overwrite, it would not.

Comment: 1. Pretty much what I was planning to do :) 2. Not an option. Basically my web app allows user-defined CSS - think JSFiddle without server round trips. Well, not quite, but something like that.

Comment: @Pumbaa80--is the user css just intended to effect a section of the page, or is it supposed to affect the whole page? Are you trying to avoid the flicker in their area, or on the whole page?

Comment: Both. I'd love to show some code, but this is a closed-source project at my company.